# What time zone does Vercel use during SSR in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, vercel

What time zone does Vercel use during SSR and static rendering in Next.js?

And a second question:
How do you change it?

In my experiments it looks to be UTC even though the region is set to Portland.

Comment: You can't change the time zone on where your application is built on Vercel. Could you share what you're trying to accomplish? In general, you likely don't want to use the time of the CI's filesystem.

Comment: @leerob I am using ISG with Apollo. Upon a page load Apollo cache is initialized with data during static generation. 
The page sends something like "fromTime" and "toTIme" to API.
If arguments that were using during static generation and upon page load mismatch there's a cache miss and static generation is useless. In order to avoid that I need to know what time zone to use for the requests. I ended up converting all time to UTC but would like to see some documentation into this process

Comment: That was going to be my recommendation - always use UTC :)

Comment: @leerob when self-hosting it seems that the system time is used